# Pivot SQL Select Result to Desired Output

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to convert a SQL result to desired output for analytic report.
Select statement and output is as follows:

```
SELECT QID, [Text], [Value] FROM TableA
```

OUTPUT SINGLE Question(QID)

[image]

OUTPUT MULTIPLE Question(QID)
[image]

Desired output result needed for report is as follows:
[image]

Can we achieve this result using Pivot table or similar way rather than using While and Cursor loop?

Thanks and regards,
Viju

Comment: Is it always the answer ID from two rows below? There is no ID tying the option text to the answer ID?

Comment: Note: Any answer anyone gives you isn't guaranteed to help because it doesn't look like you have any real way of distinguishing between each optionText. Because of this, even if someone gives you an answer that works _now_ (e.g. with a `ROW_NUMBER()` window function), there's no guarantee it will work in the future... You really need to fix your data.

Comment: @ZLK Thanks for the feedback. QID refers the question. Each question (say QID 1) might have multiple rows as shown in the code snippet. As shown , 9 rows corresponding to same question (ID = 1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Above query will not work using PIVOT id qid values are same for all the records as we have to use any aggregate function in pivot

check the below query for reference

```
DECLARE @TAB TABLE (QID INT,[TEXT] VARCHAR(255),VALUE VARCHAR(255))
INSERT INTO @TAB VALUES (1,'WEAG','SDARG'),(1,'NUM','1'),(1,'ID','1')
,(2,'WEAG','RSTHGEST'),(2,'NUM','2'),(2,'ID','2')
,(3,'WEAG','SREVFGWR'),(3,'NUM','3'),(3,'ID','3')
SELECT * FROM @TAB

SELECT * FROM 
(
SELECT T.QID,t.[TEXT],T.VALUE
FROM @TAB T
)A
PIVOT (MAX(VALUE) FOR [TEXT] IN (WEAG,ID) ) AS P
```

OUTPUT

```
QID WEAG       ID
1   SDARG       1
2   RSTHGEST    2
3   SREVFGWR    3
```